# Getting asm vars when debugging in gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have the following setup in gdb, where I have a breakpoint one line 22:

[image]

The loop code is:

```
start_loop:                             
        movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax  
        cmpl $0, %eax                   
        je exit_loop                    
        incl %edi                       
        cmpl %ebx, %eax                 
        jge start_loop                  
        movl %eax, %ebx                 
        jmp start_loop                  
exit_loop:
```

How would I view all these values in `gdb`? For example, to see what `%eax` is, what `%ebx` is, what `%edi` is, and what `data_items(,%edi,4)` is?

Comment: Try `help` in gdb. Many ways, you could do `info registers` or `p $eax` and similar. For examining memory use the `x` command.

Comment: @Jester right but when I try that I get: `>>> p %eax
A syntax error in expression, near `%eax'.
>>> p eax
No symbol "eax" in current context.`

Comment: Look more carefully. I used `$` not `%`.

Comment: Please don't show *pictures* of text. Show the text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, to see what %eax is, what %ebx is, what %edi is,

As Jester already said:

```
(gdb) info registers
(gdb) p/x $rax   # Your program appears to run on a 64-bit machine,
                 # so use $rax instead of $eax
(gdb) p/x $rbx
```

> and what data_items(,%edi,4) is

This one would be easier if you did `(gdb) disas`. Since you didn't, we don't know at what address `data_items` resides. Something like this should work:

```
(gdb) x/wx (char*)&data_items + 4 * $rdi
```